# How can I show an horizontal list after clicking a link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, header

I'd like to get something like the "share" link in the lower right corner.
https://www.celine.com/en

I tried many times using CSS only but I don't know javascript/jquery so I can't do so much actually.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking questions.

Comment: can you explain it what you want clearly?

Comment: I would like to get a sort of social list which has to appear horizontally beside the share button placed in the lower right corner, after clicking on it, like in the mentioned website

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="#" class="share"> Share </a>

<div class="share-cont">
  <!--List of social media buttons here-->
</div>
```

Initially hide the whole row by giving

```
.share-cont {
  position: absolute;
  right: -300px;
}
```

Then on click of share button, position it to 0px

```
$('.share').on('click', function() {
  $(".share-cont").animate({'right': '0px'}, 'slow');
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much phanther! How could I place the social buttons on the left of the share button?

Comment: Vary the value of css `right` property.                                               `$(".share-cont").animate({'right': '50px'}, 'slow');` may work for you.